# TapGestureRecouncer interferes with PanGestureRecouncer

Tags: c#, maui, maui-android

In my code, I am reading the movement of a finger within a specified area using `PanGestureRecognizer`. However, I encountered an issue where the `PanGestureRecognizer` event is not triggered when tapping twice, as `TapGestureRecognizer` interferes with it. My question is how to resolve this issue.

To make the problem more understandable, I have a [video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uMDyMTX1MjrfDNnXKkwQSEANrI0fa6N-/view?usp=sharing) to demonstrate the issue.

code:

```
<Border>
    <Border.GestureRecognizers>
        <PanGestureRecognizer PanUpdated="Touchpad_PanUpdate"/>
    </Border.GestureRecognizers>
</Border>
```

back:

```
private void Touchpad_PanUpdate(object sender, PanUpdatedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.StatusType == GestureStatus.Running)
    {
        DebugRunningLabel.Text = "x/y: " + Math.Round(e.TotalX, 2) + " " + Math.Round(e.TotalY, 2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> The PanGestureRecognizer event is not triggered when tapping twice.

Tapping twice on the screen is not related with the [PanGestureRecognizer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/gestures/pan?view=net-maui-8.0), it's related with [TapGestureRecognizer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/gestures/tap?view=net-maui-8.0). You can't mix them together.

If you want to make a [View](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.controls.view) recognize a tap gesture with **double taps**, you can create a [TapGestureRecognizer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/gestures/tap?view=net-maui-8.0) object, handle the Tapped event, set `NumberOfTapsRequired="2"` and add the new gesture recognizer to the GestureRecognizers collection on the view.

The following code example shows a TapGestureRecognizer attached to an Image with tapping twice:

**XAML:**

```
<Image Source="dotnet_bot.png">
    <Image.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="OnTapGestureRecognizerTapped"
                              NumberOfTapsRequired="2" />
  </Image.GestureRecognizers>
</Image>
```

**C#:**

```
void OnTapGestureRecognizerTapped(object sender, TappedEventArgs args)
{
    // Handle the tap
}
```

Comment: I would highlight that mixing the different gesture recognizers *cannot* work and why that is.